# Use the concatenation of field values as the array subscript, where the fields are specified on the command line

Tags: awk

I am creating an AWK program that I named `join`. It will be used to join two files via a composite key.

The program is run by passing it two files, `file1` and `file2`, and two variables, `flcols` ("file1 columns") and `f2cols` ("file2 columns"). The value of `flcols` and `f2cols` is a comma-separated list of numbers. The numbers identify fields, e.g., `f1cols='1,2,3,4'` means fields `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, `$4` in `file1`. Here are a couple examples of invoking the program:

```
join -v f1cols='1,2,3,4' -v f2cols='2,3,4,5' file2 file1
join -v f1cols='1,3,5' -v f2cols='1,2,3' file2 file1
```

I want to store the content of `file2` in an array named `a`. The subscripts of `a` are to be the concatenation of the values of the fields identified by `f2cols`. So, if the program is invoked like this:

```
join -v f1cols='1,2,3,4' -v f2cols='2,3,4,5' file2 file1
```

then the subscript should be:

```
a[$2,$3,$4,$5]
```

If the program is invoked like this:

```
join -v f1cols='1,3,5' -v f2cols='1,2,3' file2 file1
```

then the subscript should be:

```
a[$1,$2,$3]
```

To generalize the problem statement:

Given this command-line argument:

```
f2cols='x1,x2,...,xn'
```

where `xi` is a non-negative integer.

In the AWK program create a subscript:

```
a[$x1,$x2,...,$xn]
```

The subscript is the string resulting from concatenating the values of fields $x1,$x2,...,$xn.

I have no idea how to create such subscripts. A little help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample inputs:

```
$ head file1 file2
==> file1 <==
as,df,as,df,sd,f
1,a,2,b,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
x,xxx,y,yyy,z,a,b,c

==> file2 <==
a,b,c,d,e,f
g,h,j,k,l,m
1,2,3,4,5,6
x,y,z,a,b,c
```

One `awk` approach:

```
awk -v f1cols='1,3,5' -v f2cols='1,2,3' '
BEGIN   { FS=OFS=","
          m=split(f1cols,f1,",")
          n=split(f2cols,f2,",")
        }

FNR==NR { idx=$(f2[1])
          for (i=2;i<=n;i++)
              idx=idx FS $(f2[i])
          arr[idx]=$0
          next
        }

        { idx=$(f1[1])
          for (i=2;i<=m;i++)
              idx=idx FS $(f1[i])
          if (idx in arr)
             print "found index: " idx
        }
' file2 file1
```

This generates:

```
found index: 1,2,3
found index: x,y,z
```

Answer (score 0):

if u don't wanna use so many loops, you can dynamically generate hard-coded combo-indices, then feed it downstream to another `awk` process :

> ```
> mawk -v __='1,3,5=1,2,3' '
>
> function _____(_) {
>     sub(".","", $!(NF=NF)) + sub(".+",_)
>     return $(_<_) 
> }
> BEGIN {
>     OFS=(FS=",")"$"
>     $(!(__=split(__,___,"="))) = ","___[__]
>
>     ____=_____("(&) in __")
>     $_ = ","___[_^(_<_)]
>    
>   print ____="FNR==NR ? " _____("__[&]++") (" : ")____ }'
> ```

```
FNR==NR ? __[$1,$3,$5]++ : ($1,$2,$3) in __
```